# Intersection of determinantal varieties with linear varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, intersection-theory

Let $0<r < \min \{m,n\}$ and let $Y_r \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{mn}$ be the determinantal variety of $m$-by-$n$ matrices of rank $\le r$. Let $L \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{mn}$ be a linear variety not containing the origin such that $\dim(Y_r) = \mathrm{codim}(L)$ and $Y_r \cap L$ is nonempty. Is it true that $\dim(L \cap Y_r)=0$ for any such $L$?

Edit after @KReiser’s initial comment: Let us assume that $L$ is not contained in $Y_r$.

(Not sure if this matters, but I only care about the field $\mathbb{C}$. Any references greatly appreciated!)

Final edit: this is indeed still false. Counterexample $r=1$, $L=\begin{pmatrix} c & 1 & 0 \\ d & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ as $c,d$ vary.

Comment: Why do you think this should be true? Here is a simple counterexample: $m=n=2$, $r=1$, $L=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ c & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ as $c$ varies.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. What if we assume that $L$ is not contained in $Y_r$?

Comment: I'm relatively sure I can construct a counterexample - you probably can too. You still haven't explained *why you care*: how did you arrive at this problem?

Comment: My research is in an applied area. I have a polyhedron $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ which does not contain and intersects nontrivially with the real locus $Y_r(\mathbb{R})$ of $Y_r$. Thus, there is a $k$-dimensional face of $P$, let's call it $F$, which intersects with $Y_r(\mathbb{R})$ such that $F \cap Y_r(\mathbb{R})$ is finite. I would like $k$ to be as large as possible while maintaining the finiteness $F \cap Y_r(\mathbb{R})$. It was a shot-in-the-dark kind of guess that $k$ is $\mathrm{codim}(Y_r)$.

Comment: Ah, that's a bit different than the question in your post! You're right that over $\Bbb C$ the biggest-dimensional linear space which has finite intersection with $Y_r$ is indeed of dimension $codim(Y_r)$, but not every linear space of that dimension will have finite intersection with $Y_r$ - the relevant inequality is that for two varieties $Y,Z$ in affine space, every component of $Y\cap Z$ is of codimension at most $codim(Y)+codim(Z)$. Funny things can happen when passing to real points if the intersection is entirely within the singular locus too, but you can probably avoid that here.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I was thinking of letting $L$ to be the affine hull (over $\mathbb{C}$) of $F$. Then $L\cap Y_r$ being finite would imply $F\cap Y_r(\mathbb{R})$ being finite.